# Subtract n from min value and then remainder of n from max value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As the title says, I want to subtract n from min value and then remainder of n from max value. I thought I had this cracked until one of the values exceeds n.

My formula is `=IF(C4=D4,C4-(B4/2),IF(C4<D4,MIN(SUM(C4:D4)-B4,0),MAX(SUM(C4:D4)-B4,0)))`

The expected result in E4 should be 100 and F4 should be 69. What can I do to my existing formula to make this work correctly?

[image: Excel screen shot]

Comment: This is quite off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see the information in the EXCEL tag: "General help regarding MS Excel for single worksheet functions is available at [Super User](https://superuser.com)".

Comment: This seems as single worksheet issue. Am I missing something? OP, can you please clarify what are you trying to achieve? What is `remainder` for you in this case?

Comment: @pnuts: Hi pnuts, (A) The functions the OP is trying to use are extremely simple, and most probably to implement a very specific business logic of his own. Basic Excel tutorials are strongly advised in this case. (B) By carefully reading this question, you'll notice there are lots of missing details on it. Zipa did his best effort to try to answer the question, but without editing the question to provide these details, it is impossible to get to a conclusion. Since the OP has to rewrite the question anyway for it to be a quality question, then why not to do it in the right place? Best Regards

Comment: I know what you mean. When the question refers to Excel VBA programming, then it is always welcome. Otherwise, I follow what is in the Excel tag's description, and in [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions/90920). The Excel-formula tag mentions questions about the "structure, syntax, or output of an Excel formula", which is not the case. I'd love to answer Excel question here, but I feel some lack of support of S.O.'s question editor. A place specifically for spreadsheet questions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `E4` it seems that you want:

```
=IF(C4=D4,C4-(B4/2),IF(C4<D4,MIN(C4,D4-B4,0),MAX(C4,D4-B4,0)))
```

But I'm not sure what are you trying to do with `F4`.

Comment: @pnuts Good point, results are rubbish, if question update occurs at some point I'll edit the answer :)